# Get DatabaseException trying to run Liquibase generateChangeLog under informix

Tags: liquibase, informix

I try to run the command:

```
./liquibase --changeLogFile=./changelog.sql --defaultSchemaName=informix generateChangeLog
```

with the liquibase properties file:

```
driver: com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
classpath: ifxjdbc.jar
url: jdbc:informix-sqli://manitoba:9005/fair:INFORMIXSERVER=mf2
username:informix
password:XXXXXXXXXX
```

and get in return:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
Error executing SQL
select CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_LIST as COLUMN_NAME from informix.constraints
where constraint_type='UNIQUE' and constraint_catalog='fair'
and constraint_schema='informix' and table_name='nffilcte'
and constraint_name='nffilcte_fctrl_ix1':
The specified table (informix.constraints) is not in the database.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message says "there is no table `informix.constraints` in the database". If you didn't create the table, it's correct; there is no such table in the Informix system catalog. There is an `informix.sysconstraints` table, but that doesn't contain any of those column names. System catalogs vary between DBMS.  If you were hoping to interrogate the Informix system catalog, you'll need to use Informix system catalog table names and column names. If you're hoping for the standard "Informaation Schema" views, you have to create them — the Informix-provided ones don't include `constraints`.

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, The problem is that liquibase is supposed to support informix.  Its generating them . Is there a way to create the these so called standard information schema views?

Comment: Can anybody tell me the schema that liquibase expects for the table constraints?